# Recyclerview in Android Studio Error - "null object reference"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, null

I'm new in android and I have just screwed something.
I've used recycleView template and it worked fine but I wanted to change type of my object from string to "TagsManagerObject"  which contains

```
   private String tagName;
    private String gender;
    private String mAgeMin;
    private String mAgeMax;
    private String mDistance;
```

since then I'm stuck with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tinderapp, PID: 10921
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.tinderapp.Tags.TagsManagerAdapter$ItemClickListener.onDeleteClick(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tinderapp.Tags.TagsManagerAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(TagsManagerAdapter.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6587)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:787)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26122)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

My adapter looks like:

```
public class TagsManagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagsManagerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ImageView mDeleteImage;
    private List<TagsManagerObject> mTagsManagerObject;
    private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    public TagsManagerAdapter(Context context,List<TagsManagerObject> TagsManagerObject) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mTagsManagerObject = TagsManagerObject;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tags_manager, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      //  String tag = TagsManagerObject.get(position);
         holder.tagName.setText("#"+mTagsManagerObject.get(position).getTagName());
         holder.gender.setText(mTagsManagerObject.get(position).getGender());
         holder.distance.setText(mTagsManagerObject.get(position).getmDistance());
         holder.tagAge.setText(mTagsManagerObject.get(position).getmAgeMin() + "-" + mTagsManagerObject.get(position).getmAgeMax());
    }
    // binds the data to the TextView in each row

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTagsManagerObject.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView tagName,gender,tagAge,distance;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tagName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag);
            gender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_gender);
            distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_distance);
            tagAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_age);

            mDeleteImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_delete);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


            mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        mItemClickListener.onDeleteClick(position); <<--- HERE IS THE ERROR
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) mItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }


    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mTagsManagerObject.get(id).toString();
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

}
```

So when i click delete button it crashes. Does anyone knows why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You got this exception as you  you call `onDeleteClick(position)` on an object that is null, so you have to set a value to the `mItemClickListener` before calling this method `onDeleteClick(position)`

In your code, you have to call `setClickListener()` of your adapter in your activity/fragment that uses this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.

First, you need to check mItemClickListener for null. Doing this will prevent from null pointer exception.

```
 mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if(position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
            if(mItemClickListener !=null){
                mItemClickListener.onDeleteClick(position); <<--- HERE IS THE ERROR
             }
         }
     }
  }
);
```

And the second thing is you should set/call the **setClickListener** for the Activity/Fragment, using the **instance** of RecyclerviewAdapter.

Doing this will make the Activity/Fragment implement your **ItemClickListener** and **onDeleteClick()** method.

```
adapter.setClickListener(this);
```

Or, you can also use the **Anonymous** class here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for help. The problem was that in my acvitivy I have:

1.Created adapter with empty taglist

2.set onclicklistener

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TagsManagerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
                System.out.println("works?");
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
```

3. And then add items.

Instead

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Ive used:

```
adapter = new TagsManagerAdapter(myTagsList);
```

and that caused problem, that it coudnt find my listener